# Android GreenDao returns corrupted data

Tags: android, greendao, android-annotations

I made an app using GreenDao version 2. I met an issue that returns me back my entity without some parameters.

```
@EApplication
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static App instance = null;
    private static Context ctx;
    @Pref
    protected UserPrefs_ userPrefs;
    private DaoHelper daoHelper = new DaoHelper();

    public static UserPrefs_ getUserPrefs() {
        return instance.userPrefs;
    }

    public static Context getCtx() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static DaoSession getNewSession() {
        return getInstance().daoHelper.getSession(true, ctx);
    }

    public static DaoSession getSession() {
        return getInstance().daoHelper.getSession(false, ctx);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        ctx = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

**DaoHelper.class**

```
public class DaoHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "GreenDao";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "db";
    private static Context context = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    private DaoSession session = null;

    private DaoMaster getMaster() {
        Log.v("greenDAO", "getMaster");
        if (db == null) {
            db = getDatabase(DB_NAME, false);
        }
        return new DaoMaster(db);
    }

    public DaoSession getSession(boolean newSession, Context context) {
        Log.v("greenDAO", "getSession");
        DaoHelper.context = context;
        if (newSession) {
            return getMaster().newSession();
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = getMaster().newSession();
        }
        return session;
    }

    private synchronized SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(String name, boolean readOnly) {
        Log.v("greenDAO", "getDatabase");
        String s = "getDB(" + name + ",readonly=" + (readOnly ? "true" : "false") + ")";
        try {
            readOnly = false;
            Log.i(TAG, s);
            SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper(context, name, null);
            if (readOnly) {
                return helper.getReadableDatabase();
            } else {
                return helper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, s, ex);
            return null;
        } catch (Error err) {
            Log.e(TAG, s, err);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**DaoService.class**

```
public class DaoService {

    private static DaoSession daoSession = App_.getSession();

    public static User getMyProfile() {
        return daoSession.getUserDao()
                .queryBuilder()
                .where(UserDao.Properties.Type.eq(BuildConfig.FLAVOR))
                .list()
                .get(0);
    }
}
```

I have 2 cases when I call `DaoService.getMyProfile()`:

a) when I launch the app via activity, after I call that method I receive my user with all his data (username,phone number, email etc.)

b) when I call that method from a background service I receive my user just with a couple of parameters, instead of all parameters like in case a)

Is there any wrong implementation or missed anything ?

Comment: Did you cross-check against the DB file?

Comment: Well other db connections i dont do in that time

Comment: I was referring to getting the SQLite database file and opening in some SQLite client app.

Comment: I have no issue regarding that. I connect to db, have the session, but this session doesn't return me valid info (can say incomplete)